# C++ including string

Tags: string, c++-cli

Hey im trying to create Windows Form Application program but i have a problem with defining string

Fam.cpp

```
#include "Fam.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;
using namespace Project1; 

[STAThread]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew Fam());
    return 0;
}
```

Part of Fam.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    int IloscBD1=0, IloscBD2=0, IloscPD1, IloscPD2, Suma, I, J, Punkty, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, Druzyna;
    string a;
```

And here are errors that im getting

> Error 1   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
>   Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

I have tried as well changing string a; to  std::string a; but then im getting those errors:

> Error 1   error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std'
>   Error 2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
>   Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

Comment: use `<>` instead of `" "` to surround your `std::` library includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to include string on your header, because that's where you use it.

Part of Fam.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace Project1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;


    int IloscBD1=0, IloscBD2=0, IloscPD1, IloscPD2, Suma, I, J, Punkty, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, Druzyna;
    std::string a;

}
```